# Reading serial port in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm beginner in Java. I'm reading data from device through serial port. I'm getting data for every one minute, but first reading is coming half, after that data is coming correctly.

Output I'm getting is:

> 6050.003120815340006050.003120815350006050.0

Correct output should be like this:

> 03120815340006050.003120815350006050.0

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; //import gnu.io.*;
import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;
byte[] readBuffer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    System.out.println("portList... " + portList);
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            System.out.println("port identified is Serial.. "
                    + portId.getPortType());
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM2")) {
                System.out.println("port identified is COM2.. "
                        + portId.getName());
                // if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
            } else {
                System.out.println("unable to open port");
            }
        }
    }
}

public SimpleRead() {
    try {
        System.out.println("In SimpleRead() contructor");
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp1111",500);
        System.out.println(" Serial Port.. " + serialPort);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println("Port in use Exception");
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(" Input Stream... " + inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);

    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        System.out.println("Tooo many Listener exception");
    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {

        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // no handshaking or other flow control
        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

        // timer on any read of the serial port
        serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(500);

        System.out.println("................");

    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        System.out.println("UnSupported comm operation");
    }
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("In run() function ");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        // System.out.println();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted Exception in run() method");
    }
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

    // System.out.println("In Serial Event function().. " + event +
    // event.getEventType());
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
    /*
     * case SerialPortEvent.BI: case SerialPortEvent.OE: case
     * SerialPortEvent.FE: case SerialPortEvent.PE: case SerialPortEvent.CD:
     * case SerialPortEvent.CTS: case SerialPortEvent.DSR: case
     * SerialPortEvent.RI: case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY: break;
     */
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        readBuffer = new byte[8];

        try {

            while (inputStream.available()>0) {

                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            //   System.out.println("Number of bytes read " + numBytes);
            }

            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception in SerialEvent()");
        }
        break;
    }
    // System.out.println();
/*  String one = new String(readBuffer);
    char two = one.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Character at three: " + two);*/
}

}
```

Comment: Please add four blanks in front of the first lines, so that it is formatted as code.

Comment: Did you just copy that from another site? -- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
while (inputStream.available()>0) {
  int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
  System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
}
```

You are printing the result out of the while loop. However the code inside the loop may run more than once, so chunk of data will be lost.

Comment: i tried the above code but the serialEvent method doesnt get executed.Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

Try flushing the input buffer of the port before doing your read. Otherwise, if the sending end has sent data during your program's startup (or closely before, that might be up to the operating system), you will get old buffered data.

Also, if possible, consider adding *message framing* to the protocol, so you can detect when you have read something that is not, in fact, a complete message, and discard it. This is often very helpful with these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2):

This looks as if you were reading the rest of some message which was sent before you started.

Try to read as much data as possible as you start the program to clear any hardware buffers. After that, start your processing.