# Sending a string to a COM port

Tags: java, serial-port, jbutton

First project, its only out of interest so i can learn.

I am trying to make an app that will send a string down a comm port. Below is my GUI (first attempt!)

I have created buttons and they do things but now i need to add the com port functionality.

Please can someone give me a pointer?  In the most simple language possible please. I am self taught.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;



public class AlarmGenerator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public AlarmGenerator() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();


    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField1.setText("Enter Custom String Here");
    jTextField2.setText("Result");
    jButton1.setText("Alarm1");
    jButton2.setText("Alarm2");
    jButton3.setText("Alarm3");
    jButton4.setText("Custom Alarm");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()               

                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)    
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2)

    )));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addComponent(jButton4)
            .addComponent(jTextField1)
            .addComponent(jTextField2)

            .addContainerGap(0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();

    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2.setText("Alarm 1 Activated, String: "+alarm1);
        }
    });

    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2.setText("Alarm 2 Activated, String: "+alarm2);
        }
    });

    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2.setText("Alarm 3 Activated, String: "+alarm3);
        }
    });

    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2.setText("Custom alarm, string sent: "+jTextField1.getText ());
        }
    });
}                       

public static void main(String args[]) {        

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AlarmGenerator().setVisible(true);


        }
    });


}

// Variables declaration                    
private static javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
String alarm1 = "Hello";
String alarm2 = "Bye";
String alarm3 = "Custom";
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Class 2

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class TwoWaySerialComm {
public TwoWaySerialComm() {
    super();
}

void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier
            .getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    } else {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                2000);

        if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
        }
    }
}

/** */
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {
    InputStream in;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        try {
            while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, len));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/** */
public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {
    OutputStream out;

    public SerialWriter(OutputStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = System.in.read()) > -1) {
                this.out.write(c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        (new TwoWaySerialComm()).connect("COM3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this link.

It will give more insight in how to send data via COM port

[How to send data to COM PORT using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900950/how-to-send-data-to-com-port-using-java)

this page links to some of the possible answers

[Java Serial Communication on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows)

[Is there Java library or framework for accessing Serial ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747539/is-there-java-library-or-framework-for-accessing-serial-ports)

[Reading serial port in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336714/reading-serial-port-in-java)

and two other answers which are basically equal as the reading serial ports answer.

```
private TwoWaySerialComm twoWaySerCom;

public AlarmGenerator() {

    initComponents();   

    twoWaySerCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();

    try {

        twoWaySerCom.connect("COM1");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I noticed you have multiple

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
```

in your project those are project entries and one should be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, Thanks of the pointers.  I have read through those but they are a little advanced for me.  I have added the RXTX Api and i created a new class using an example i found on the internet.  See below.  How to i pass the string from the first class to the second class?

Comment: Patrick I have edited my answer you should be able to use it this way

Comment: Hi Blaatz0r, Thanks for your assistance i did that and i can now open the Com port.  I have a jbutton and i want to send the string that is String 1 on the button press. can you give another pointer on that?

Comment: Hi Patrick what you want to do is to convert your string to an array of bytes. that can be transfered by a send. I won't be able to go into this directly (@ the office :)) but will try to get to this tonight when I get back.

Comment: In such a case it is common practice to use the COMPort object as a field (e.g define it in the class and not in a function) so you can reference the object.

below is some pseudo code

class x

public x ()
{
   port = new comport();
}

private COMPort port;



public onbuttonclick()
{
   comport.Write( ("string value").tobytearray() );
}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, I've created a Java package, j232, and native library, libj232, that's open source and hosted on GitHub. It should be considered a 'work-in-progress' and currently only handles synchronous serial data.

The main Java package is [here](https://github.com/jtkb/j232) and its associated native library [here](https://github.com/jtkb/libj232). Also take a look at the [wiki for j232](https://github.com/jtkb/j232/wiki) and finally the [example page](https://github.com/jtkb/j232/wiki/Examples).